# How to get the time in ms between two calls in Python

Tags: python, precision, timing

How does one properly get the number of millis between two successive calls? There's a bunch of different ways to get or profile time, and all of them seem to have problems:

- `time.clock()` is deprecated
- `time.time()` is based on the system's clock to determine seconds since epoch and has [unreliable leap second handling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time)
- `time.process_time()` and `time.thread_time()` can't be used because they ignore time spent sleeping
- `time.monotonic()` only ticks 64 times per second
- `time.perf_counter()` has lossy nano precision encoded as float
- `time.perf_counter_ns()` has precise nano resolution but encoded as int, so can't track more than 4 seconds

Of these, `time.perf_counter()` is the only option for millisecond precision (i.e. most use cases) but is there something better? (e.g. some kind of `perf_counter_ms` that yields an `int` but with a reliability interval of four million seconds instead of 4 seconds?)

Comment: How can timezones & leap seconds affect measuring milliseconds?

Comment: by having someone or something change the system clock. updated the "why it'll be wrong" for that one.

Comment: `perf_counter_ns` returns a *Python* `int`, not a 32-bit integer. There's no 4-second cap on the interval it can measure.

Comment: So you're saying the system clock can arbitrarily change?

Comment: Ever had an NTTP server glitch on you?

Comment: @chepner I can't seem to find reliable information on bits per Python int, pretty all I can find claims that python ints are 32 bit. If it has more (or arbitrary) bits, that would certainly moot this question.

Comment: `time.time()` is the right way.  You can't win the "system clock changes" battle.  Statistically, the odds that the system clock will change in any given second are insignificant.

Comment: Then your information is 30 years old.  Python ints have infinite size.  You can make an int as large as your memory.

Comment: I have no idea where you go the idea that Python ints are 32 bits. ["Integers have unlimited precision."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `time.perf_counter_ns()` has precise nano resolution but encoded as int, so can't track more than 4 seconds

This is incorrect. `perf_counter_ns` returns an [arbitrary-precision Python `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex), not a 32-bit integer. As a result, it's *not* limited to returning a value of 2**32 nanoseconds or less. You can divide the difference between two return values by 1,000,000 to get the number of milliseconds.

```
>>> from time import sleep, perf_counter_ns as pcns
>>> t1 = pcns(); sleep(5); (pcns() - t1) / 1_000_000
5000.45865
```